# NestJS Force body parameter to values based on type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings

First of all, I'm only asking this because I didn't found an answer **that fits this case.** Also I just started learning NestJS.

I have the following declaration:

```js
// Type definition of options
type Gender = "Male" | "Female";

// DTO
export class User {
    ...
    gender: Gender;
}

// Inside controller
...
@Post()
registerUser(@Body() data: User) {
    console.log(data.gender);
}
...
```

Unfortunately, if it set, in the body, gender to "Unknown", it will be the value of data.gender even though it's not inside of the interval of values allowed. I would like to restrict values to the only those available in the type definition. I've seen examples on how to do it in enumerations but none on types.
Is it possible to restrict them using types?

Comment: See the docs around validation here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> npm i --save class-validator class-transformer

Make changes in main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());  <= add this
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And try like this

```
import { IsDefined, IsIn, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

// DTO
export class User {
    ...

    @IsDefined()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsIn(['Male','Female'])
    gender: Gender;
}

// Inside controller
...
@Post()
registerUser(@Body() data: User) {
    console.log(data.gender);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it.

Comment: Superb, Welcome.

Comment: tell me one thing what we wrote the type in schema of user